# How to specify product IDs in Google Search "application/ld+json" script without getting "Missing product ID (optional)"

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld, structured-data, google-search-console

How can I reduce warning of "Missing product ID (optional)" on "application/ld+json" script in google search console?

Below My sample JSON-LD code

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "done product Name here",
  "url": "done product url here",
  "image": [
      "done image url here"
    ],
  "description": "done description here",
  "sku": "H100000001",
  "productID" : "9876543210",  // Added like this type behaviour
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "cosmetics"
  },
  "offers": [{
        "@type" : "Offer",
        "sku": "H100000002",
        "availability" : "http://schema.org/InStock",
        "price" : "26.0",
        "priceCurrency" : "USD",
        "url" : "product url"
      },
      {
        "@type" : "Offer",
        "sku": "H100000003",
        "availability" : "http://schema.org/InStock",
        "price" : "26.0",
        "priceCurrency" : "USD",
        "url" : "product url"
      },
      {
        "@type" : "Offer",
        "sku": "H099020004",
        "availability" : "http://schema.org/InStock",
        "price" : "26.0",
        "priceCurrency" : "USD",
        "url" : "product url"
      }]
}
</script>
```

I have tried different variables of product id below

```
1. "productID" : "9876543210",

2. "productID" : "isbn:9876543210",

3. "product-id" : "isbn:9876543210",

4. "product-id" : "9876543210",
```

but error still getting.

[image]

Can anyone help how can I solve the issue of Missing product ID (optional)"  on Google Search Console?

Which behavior is correct for set product id in ld+json?

Comment: "productID" is the correct format. Are you using the live test? It will take time for any edits to become indexed and show in the indexed result.

Comment: you mean like "productID": "9876543210",  which I have set on the above json code? yes after set "productID" I have tested on the live test. but not get any update it still gets a warning message.

Comment: That should work. In the live test you can inspect the rendered html. Double check your structured data is how you expect it to be.

Comment: OK, @TonyMcCreath above code is correct? Can you Please confirm.

Comment: It looks good to me

Comment: @TonyMcCreath I got "Validation Failed" with above json

Comment: Then it's not good. A bit more detail please. It works in the SDTT for me.

Comment: SDTT? you mean google search console test?

Comment: Structured Data Testing Tool. It's nit as good as the GSC tool, but all we have as outsiders.

Comment: Yes In Structured Data test tool, there are not displayed this issue. But In Google Console Console, We have a face. see screenshot. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vgPYU6NFKXAgP4bqB9-YD5XGm77PQSfn/view

Comment: Google haven't told us what productID is for yet. So I would not worry too much about it. I'd insert an internal id that I'd use for the merchant feed and Facebook feed.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath means there is no way to reduce this warning?

Comment: Without adding a value to it, no. If you have a merchant feed or Facebook adverting I would insert the same values they use.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please provide an example or doc information regarding that so How can I apply on site? using facebook adverting or merchant feed. and after applying this, waring will be removed?

Comment: It's down to how your system works, which I do not know. Do you use the Google merchant centre. What IDs does that use. Do you do product advertising on Facebook. How do you ID product there? Does your system have internal product IDs?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is not about programming in the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 2):

The message from Google is not very clear... what it's looking for is one of product IDs from https://schema.org/Product (gtin13, etc.). I was getting the same error after adding ProductID, but once I replaced ProductID with the gtinxxx values, the warning went away.